# How to correctly definde a global struct variable?

Tags: c, struct

In `file1.c` I have :

```
struct node
{
    int key;
    jobPtr jobX;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
void method()
{
 ...
}
```

I want to use `head` pointer in `file2.c`. So I add into header file `headerX.h`:

```
extern struct node *head;
```

In `file2.c` I do this:

```
struct node *head;
int main() {

}
```

But in `file2.c` I can't use `head`. What have I done incorrectly?

**UPD**

I removed `struct node *head` in file2.c file but I can't still use `head` pointer. My IDE allows me to type `head` in file2.c but when I want to call elements of `structure` IDE gives me `no suggestions for members of struct node *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `head` in two places.

This is a **declaration**:

```
extern struct node *head;
```

While this is a **definition**:

```
struct node *head;
```

There should be only one definition, so remove the one in file2.c.

EDIT:

Besides the `extern` declaration, your header file should also contain the definition of `struct node`:

```
struct node {
    // define fields here
};
```

Comment: Should I only leave `node *head` ?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich There should be only one instance of `struct node *head` in one file.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich The struct definition needs to be in your header file, not file1.c.  Otherwise, the definition isn't visible to file2.c.